# to create quiz using StartDrag and stopDrag

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Actually i have a quiz.fla. In the file ,two of them fill inthe blank questions and others are
multiple questions.

square1_mc must run only once not twice. İf user correct selected,  doesnt run it again.
However,if mybadscoretext is 1 not increase 2,3,4. :S
how i can do all?

```
stop();

var myScore:Number = 0;
var myBadScore:Number=0;

square1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);



function drag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 e.target.startDrag();
}

function drop(e:MouseEvent):void
{

 square1_mc.stopDrag();
 if (square1_mc.hitTestObject(square2_mc)== true)
 {

square1_mc.x=129;
square1_mc.y=133;
 this.graphics.clear();
this.graphics.lineStyle(2, 000000);
this.graphics.moveTo(square1_mc.x, square1_mc.y);
this.graphics.lineTo(square2_mc.x, square2_mc.y);
this.graphics.endFill();


myScore += 1;
score_txt.text=String(myScore);
square1_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);



 }

 else 
 { 

square1_mc.x=129;
square1_mc.y=133;
myBadScore += 1;
mybadscore_txt.text=String(myBadScore);


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable to keep track of whether the bad score has been added:

```
var badMarked:Boolean = false;

function drag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.startDrag();
    badMarked = false;
}

[...]

function drop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (square1_mc.hitTestObject(square2_mc)== true)
    {
    [...]
    }
    else if ( !badMarked  )
    { 
        square1_mc.x=129;
        square1_mc.y=133;
        myBadScore += 1;
        mybadscore_txt.text=String(myBadScore);
        badMarked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How i can set previous score if user want to change the answer?

Comment: Then just put a decrement in the "right answer" section:  `if ( badMarked ){ myBadScore -= 1; }`

Comment: Thanks for reply, iND. But i have a quiz.fla. In the file, two of qestions fill in the blank and other multiple questions. quiz.fla runs correctly. I want to add startdarg the question.it, total three questions. How i can set it?

Comment: I am really not sure what you are asking. . .

Comment: is possible you can see the quiz.fla file? Can i add file in here?

Comment: Sure, I can take a look.  But just put it on your website, and post a link to it.  You can always take the file away later.

Comment: if user want to change the answer, i think,i need knowlodge about xml to create the quiz. İs there another way?

Comment: You need to ask this in another question.